# Nomen-Nomen-Konstruktionen

Tags: grammatical-case, usage, word-order, noun

Wann können im Deutschen zwei Nomen/Substantive hintereinander stehen?

Ich meine:

1. durch die Satzstellung ("Hier können alle Hunde Spielzeug bekommen")
2. durch Genitivkonstruktionen ("ihres Atems Kraft")
3. Eigennamen ("Anna Müller")

Was ist aber mit Konstruktionen wie "Sie beklagten auf ihrer Seite Verletzte" oder "ein Glas Wein"? Auch da sind zwei aufeinanderfolgende Nomen möglich. Wo kann man die genauen Regeln nachlesen?

Danke und liebe Grüße

Comment: Was ist an aufeinanderfolgenden Nomen so besonders? Nomen stehen hintereinander, wenn sich das im Satz so ergibt. Dafür braucht es keine besonderen Regeln.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es gibt im Deutschen keine Regel, die direkt aufeinanderfolgende Nomen verbietet. Es gibt allerding auch keine Regel, die das erlaubt. Ob Nomen direkt aufeinanderfolgen können oder nicht, hängt in deinen Beispielen von zwei grammatischen Regeln ab:

1. Die Ordnung der Satzglieder. Die ist im Deutschen nicht vorgeschrieben, und Subjekt und Objekt können an fast beliebiger Stelle stehen, solange sichergestellt ist, dass das Verb an Position 2 steht (Deutsch ist keine Sprache mit *SPO-Satzstellung*, sondern mit *Verb-Zweitstellung*). Durch diese relativ freizügige Satzstellung können natürlich auch Subjekt und Objekt aneinandergeraten. Diesen Grundastz hast du in deiner Frage schon erwähnt.
2. Selbst wenn Subjekt und Objekt in einem Satz direkt aneinandergeraten, steht normalerweise noch ein Artikel dazwischen und damit die Nomen nicht direkt beieinander. Eine weitere Regel bestimmt, unter welchen Umständen der Artikel zu einem Substantiv weggelassen werden kann/muss (und dadurch die Nomen direkt beieinanderstehen). Manche Grammatiken nennen den weggelassenen Artikel *Nullartikel*. Die genauen Regeln sind ein bißchen komplizierter, aber im Wesentlichen geschieht das dann, wenn es sich um Nichtzählbares ("Wein", "Milch", "Gemüse",...) oder um ein Nomen im Plural, das normalerweise einen unbestimmten Artikel tragen würde ("Verletzte", "Flaschen"...).

Die genauen Regeln solltest du unter den entsprechenden Stichworten hier oder in einer guten Grammatik finden.